# Should be a way to flag "tricky" review audits

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

I just failed one of the "questionable audits."  I selected "leave open", because it was one where if the user came back and gave more info about what they were having trouble with it would have been perfectly fine.   Someone already commented "post your attempts" so in my mind its on the user to come back and explain.

I think there should be some way to "flag" down-vote some of the audit questions.  Because the misleading / questionable ones are unfair.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727561/merge-words-from-two-separate-text-files-and-save-different-permutations-of-each

Comment: That's not a tricky audit; you don't vote based on "what the question could be", you vote based on "what the question is."  If the user goes back and updates the question, awesome, vote to re-open it.  There's no way that question warranted a "Leave Open" vote.

Comment: Same as I mentioned below...    The question isn't did I do the right thing. Its the idea of letting people (who have different views as you) express concerns about a particular audit being challenging

Comment: How would, downvoting an audit work? wouldn't it result in everyone who fails an audit downvoting it? If you failed the audit, you clearly disagree with it (or are a robo reviewer.) doesn't seem that useful.

Comment: Okay, but now you're clogging this hypothetical new flag queue with invalid flags, because in this case, you would want to flag an audit that isn't "tricky" and shouldn't have been failed in the first place.  And if you find a legitimately bad audit (and I agree, they're out there), you can simply downvote the question, and it won't show up in any more audits.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables didn't know that you can downvote the question and that would make it not show up any more.

Comment: There's no reason not to put a question on hold that doesn't have enough information. Either the user abandons it (thus saving everyone from wasting their time) or they come back and "give more info about what they were having trouble with" and it can be reopened.  Win-win.

Answer (score 11):

> I selected "leave open", because it was one where **if the user came back** and gave more info about what they were having trouble with **it would have been perfectly fine**.

So, you concur that, as it stands, the post is not acceptable.
Which means it should be closed.

---

Now to flagging review-audits you disagree with:

1. In some cases, you can take them out of circulation by opening the post and doing the right thing (upvote/downvote/closevote/reopen-vote, in special cases flag for intervention).
2. Aside from that, there's an answer to a feature-request: ["This audit is incorrect"-button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790).

Comment: The question isn't did I do the right thing.  Its the idea of letting people (who have different views as you) express concerns about a particular audit being challenging.

Comment: I think my addition took care of that. Please check.

Answer (score 9):

That's not a tricky review audit. That question should be put on hold until the OP makes the required edits.

Comment: If there was a hold button I would have used it.

Comment: vote to close puts it on hold.

Comment: @KevinB did not know that.  Thanks.